# Ruby creating sentences with substrings while maintaining order

Tags: ruby

I am currently working on a Ruby problem in which I am essentially creating my own language. Below (nouns, verbs, articles) can be thought as words. However, in order to create a valid sentence, I must have a verb, a noun, or at least 2 articles.

Nouns: "abcd", "c", "def", "h", "ij, "cde"

Verbs: "bc", "fg", "g", "hij", "bcd"

Articles: "a", "ac", "e"

So what I am trying to do is basically write a method that takes a string and returns all possible valid sentences (while keeping characters in the same order and inserting a space between the words)

ex. input = `"abcdefg"` 
returns the list

```
[ "a bc def g", "a bcd e fg", "abcd e fg"]
```

So I tried breaking down the problem and this is what I have so far

```
alpha = "abcdefg"



nouns = ["abcd", "c", "def", "h", "ij", "cde"]
verbs = ["bc", "fg", "g", "hij", "bcd"]
articles = ["a", "ac", "e"]

verbArray = [];
nounArray = [];
articleArray = [];

nouns.each do |item|
  if alpha.include?(item)
    nounArray << item
  end
end

verbs.each do |item|
  if alpha.include?(item)
    verbArray << item
  end
end

articles.each do |item|
  if alpha.include?(item)
    articleArray << item
  end
end


puts nounArray.inspect => ["abcd", "c", "def", "cde"]
puts verbArray.inspect => ["bc", "fg", "g", "bcd"]
puts articleArray.inspect => ["a", "e"]
```

My thought process was that I first wanted to get all possible combinations for each of the words (nouns, verb, article). I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to approach this problem but beyond this step I was trying without much success to form ordered sentences.

I've been searching stacks and other websites for types of combinations/sorting techniques plus I am trying to avoid using regex at the moment. I would honestly appreciate any direction/feedback as how to continue my journey to solving this problem.Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is there ary restriction on `verb/noun/article` order?

Comment: Also, `I must have a verb, a noun, or at least 2 articles. ` is ambiguous.

Comment: The example values look quite cryptic. Is there a good reason not to use actual (or maybe fake but pronounceable) nouns, verbs, and articles?

Comment: There is no restriction on order for a verb, noun, or article as long as the original order remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible without Regex, but you'll have a hard time writing anything without recursion :

```
grammar = {
  noun: ["abcd", "c", "def", "h", "ij", "cde"],
  verb: ["bc", "fg", "g", "hij", "bcd"],
  article:  ["a", "ac", "e"]}

def find_sentences(text, grammar, head = [], structure = [])
  if text.empty?
    if structure.include?(:verb) || structure.include?(:noun) || structure.count(:article) > 2
      puts "Sentence found : "
      puts head.join(' ')
      puts structure.join(' ')
      puts
    end
  else
    grammar.each do |type, words|
      words.each do |word|
        if text.start_with?(word)
          find_sentences(text.slice(word.size..-1), grammar, head + [word], structure + [type])
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

find_sentences("abcdefg", grammar)
```

It outputs :

```
Sentence found :
abcd e fg
noun article verb

Sentence found :
a bc def g
article verb noun verb

Sentence found :
a bcd e fg
article verb article verb
```

Comment: Good solution, Eric. You might want to pare down `grammar` as an optimization before doing anything else: `str = "abcdefg"; gram = grammar.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = v.select { |s| str.include?(s) } } #=> {:noun=>["abcd", "c", "def", "cde"], :verb=>["bc", "fg", "g", "bcd"], :article=>["a", "e"]}`.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. Given the OP code, I didn't want to invest too much time either.

Comment: I wrote another recursive solution, but it's nowhere near as nice as yours. Your solution will have some take-aways for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of writing a recursive method.

```
def all_sentences(str, grammar)
  gram = grammar.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
    v.select { |s| str.include?(s) }.each { |s| h[s] = k } }
  recurse(str, gram.keys, gram, '')
end

def recurse(str, parts, gram, partial)
  p = partial.delete(' ')
  parts.each_with_object([]) do |part, arr|
    combine = p + part
    next unless str.start_with?(combine)
    s = (partial + ' ' + part).lstrip
    if combine.size == str.size
      arr << s if valid?(s, gram)
    else
      arr.concat(recurse(str, parts, gram, s))
    end
  end
end

def valid?(candidate, gram)
  arr = candidate.split
  arr.any? { |s| [:noun, :verb].include?(gram[s]) } ||
    arr.count { |s| gram[s] == :article } > 1
end
```

**Example**

```
grammar = {
  noun: ["abcd", "c", "def", "h", "ij", "cde"],
  verb: ["bc", "fg", "g", "hij", "bcd"],
  article:  ["a", "ac", "e"]
}

str = "abcdefg"

all_sentences(str, grammar)
  #=> ["abcd e fg", "a bc def g", "a bcd e fg"]
```

**Note**

For the example, the hash `gram` is computed as follows.

```
gram = grammar.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  v.select { |s| str.include?(s) }.each { |s| h[s] = k } }
  #=> {"abcd"=>:noun, "c"=>:noun, "def"=>:noun, "cde"=>:noun,
  #    "bc"=>:verb, "fg"=>:verb, "g"=>:verb, "bcd"=>:verb,
  #    "a"=>:article, "e"=>:article}
```

Notice that as well as mapping words into parts of speech, I have removed a few "words" that cannot be part of the "sentence" `str`.

It strikes me that

```
words_to_pos = grammar.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| v.each { |s| h[s] = k } }
  #=> {"abcd"=>:noun, "c"=>:noun, "def"=>:noun, "h"=>:noun, "ij"=>:noun,
  #    "cde"=>:noun, "bc"=>:verb, "fg"=>:verb, "g"=>:verb, "hij"=>:verb,
  #    "bcd"=>:verb, "a"=>:article, "ac"=>:article, "e"=>:article}
```

would have been a more convenient data structure than the original `grammar` ("pos" for "part of speech").

Comment: "set" is a noun and a verb, so your structure might not work.

Comment: Eric, joshh45's language is called "Bishna". One of it's characteristics (as in the example) is that every word is exactly one part of speech (similar to Umzergi). If the language were changed to permit a word to be more than one part of speech we could deal with that by merely modifying `grammar`: remove all but one instance of each word, with preference for the one remaining being noun or verb, then article.

Answer (score 0):

solved using recursion and lambda in ruby :

```
@nouns = ["abcd", "c", "def", "h", "ij", "cde"]
@verbs = ["bc", "fg", "g", "hij", "bcd"]
@articles = ["a", "ac", "e"]
@return_arr = []
def solve(idx, hash, ans = [])
    # base case
    if (idx >= $str.length) and  ( hash['vs'] >= 1) and (hash['ns'] >= 1 or hash['as'] >= 2)
        @return_arr << ans.join(" ")
        return
    end
    # define lamda to do common operation
    execute = lambda do |var, i|
        hash[var] += 1
        ans << $str[idx..i]
        solve(i+1, hash, ans)
        ans.pop
        hash[var] -= 1
    end
    #check for nouns, verbs, articles
    $str.each_char.with_index do |c,i|
        next if i < idx
        execute.call('ns', i) if @nouns.include? $str[idx..i]
        execute.call('vs', i) if @verbs.include? $str[idx..i]
        execute.call('as', i)if @articles.include? $str[idx..i]
    end
end

$str = gets.strip
hash = Hash.new(0)
solve(0, hash)
p @return_arr
```

Input : `abcdefg`

Output : `["a bc def g", "a bcd e fg", "abcd e fg"]`